# How to make a table with fixed columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

I need the table with Fixed Columns in Odoo 10 so am including script files from [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html) link.

Also created JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uL0a10sm/7/:

```
 <template id="rfq_assets_backend" name="rfq assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">             
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/RFQ_form_widgets.js"></script>                              
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/purchase_requisition/static/src/css/rfq_form.css" />  
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/purchase_requisition/static/src/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/purchase_requisition/static/src/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.css" />
         <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> -->
         <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>             
         <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
        </xpath>
  </template>
```

form_view.js

```
    var table = self.$el.find('#vendor_form').DataTable( {
                    scrollY:        "300px",
                    scrollX:        true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging:         false,
                    fixedColumns:   {
                        leftColumns: 1,
                        rightColumns: 1
                    }
             });
```

`View.xml`:

```
  <t t-name="rfq_form">
    <table id="vendor_form" class="stripe row-border order-column" >      
    <thead>       
    <th>Product</th>
    <t t-foreach="all_vendors" t-as="vendor"> 
        <th class="rfq_head"><t t-esc="vendor.partner_name"/> </th>
    </t>
    <th>Final Choose</th>
    <th>Ring the vendor by</th>
    </thead>
    <t t-foreach="lines" t-as="line">
    <tr t-att-class="pol" t-att-data-lineid="line.id" t-att-data-selected="selected">
        <td class="cell_product_name"><t t-esc="line.product_name"/></td>
        <t t-foreach="all_vendors" t-as="vendor">
        <t t-set="i" t-value="0"></t>
          <t t-foreach="line.partners" t-as="partner">
            <t t-if="vendor.partner_id == partner.partner_id">
                <td>
                 <div class="rfq_head edit_price"> 
                    <input type="text" name="price" t-att-value="partner.price_unit"/>
                    <input type="text" name="sdiscount"/>
                    <input type="number" name="bonus"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="select_partner"/>
                 </div> 
                </td> 
                <t t-set="i" t-value="1"></t>
            </t>                
          </t> 
           <t t-if="i==0">
            <td></td>
           </t>
        </t>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    </t>
    </table>  
</t>
```

I am getting below error:

If inherit jquery lib jquery-1.12.4.js, I am getting the error:

> `$.().popover` is not a function

If lib not inherited or replaced I neither get `fixedcolumns` nor any errors.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

**The order of embedded scripts does matter**, as it's described in the given [site](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html).

You have to load `jQuery` lib first, then the jQuery ext `dataTables`, then the `fixedColumns`. The jQuery import is not necessary, because it's already imported in `/web/views/webclient_templates.xml`. Try this:

```xml
<template id="fc_assets_backend" name="account assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.css"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Also, make sure that you've already had all those `dataTables.fixedColumns.js`, `jquery.dataTables.js` files in

```
/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/
```

You didn't mention which Odoo version you're using, I gave the answer based on 11 version.

Comment: Am using Odoo 10 version
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js']">' cannot be located in parent view

Comment: @Silviaa I just edited my answer, please re-check if it solves your issue. It basically looks like your solution, but it has a different order of JS file integration.

Comment: Other files inherited but cant inherit this file <script type="text/javascript" src="/purchase_requisition/static/src/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
Am getting error  web.assets_common.js:3617 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

Comment: You don't have to replace the built-in jquery lib of Odoo 10. It's 1.11 version while the `datatable` requires jquery 1.7+. So just remove that script out of your code.

Comment: If i remove it works but i cant get the fixed columns output as per this https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Comment: It's weird. If you really want to replace the odoo's jquery lib. Use this

    `<xpath expr="//script[@src='/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js']" position="replace">
      <script src="your-jquery-here"></script>
    </xpath>`

Comment: Please edit your question and show the latest version of your code

Comment: Edited my question please check

Comment: You didn't get `datatable` because you didn't integrate your `form_view.js` file. The code is not triggered to make table displayed as expected.